# Angullar 11 error getting Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') with primeng p-multiselect

Tags: primeng, angular11

I am using primeng multiselect . When the component gets initialized i am populating the values but getting the following error and doesn't show where it occurs.

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

here is my template:

```
<p-multiSelect
        #multiSelect
        [options]="entityItemOptions"
        [(ngModel)]="selectedEntityItems"
        optionLabel="name"
        dropdownIcon="fas fa-caret-down"
        [placeholder]="placeholderText"
        display="chip"
        [optionValue]="config?.optionValue"
        [disabled]="!hasSubjectType"
        (onChange)="onCustomItemChange()"
    >
        <ng-template let-subOption pTemplate="item">
            <span class="truncate-option-text">{{ subOption?.name }}</span>
        </ng-template>
    </p-multiSelect>
```

component:

```
public entityItemOptions: SelectOption<number, string>[];
```

Answer (score 0):

Initializing the array with following fixed my issue.

```
public entityItemOptions: SelectOption<number, string>[] = [];
```